# jhipster, admin role identification on Java side

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jhipster

recently I started working on jhipster angular application (employee-targets app). By default I am getting entries for all users, so to restrict it to current user, I have modified the code to :

In `EmployeeTargetsResource.java`
for  `@GetMapping("/emp-targets")`

I have changed

`empTargetsRepository.findAll()` to `empTargetsRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser()`

But now I want to change this based on role:

if the logged in user is `admin`, I want to have  `empTargetsRepository.findAll()`

otherwise `empTargetsRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser()`

Is there is any global variable available to check whether the current logged in user is admin in Java code?

For angular code I could able to get using `*jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'"` for html. Is there any similar option available in Java code side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/6e42d1c7bfee34463caafeaf5430459ee0d16af2/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/SecurityUtils.java#L69-L75) which will return a boolean if the user has the `ROLE_ADMIN` authority.

So your code would look similar to below:

```java
if (SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {
    empTargetsRepository.findAll()
} else {
    empTargetsRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser()
}
```